# Efficient way to clone a Map of Lists?

Tags: java, dictionary

For my project, I needed a type of dictionary where I can access a list of values by key but also be able to get the key by a value. To accomplish this, I made a new Class that holds two HashMaps:

```
private final Map<K, List<V>> kvMap;
private final Map<V, K> vkMap;
```

I also want to be able to clone this kind of map. My current solution is

```
public InverseSurjectiveMap(InverseSurjectiveMap<K, V> map) {
    this.kvMap = new HashMap<>(map.kvMap);

    for (K key : map.kvMap.keySet()) {
        kvMap.put(key, new LinkedList<>(kvMap.get(key)));
    }

    this.vkMap = new HashMap<>(map.vkMap);
}
```

Is there a more time efficient way to do this copying: reducing time complexity in favour of memory complexity. Thanks!

Edit:
I need is that changing the list of the initial map doesn't change the list of the copied map and vice-versa. I would like for the actual elements to reference the same instances.

Comment: I think the first thing to point out is that this doesn't make copies of any elements `K` or `V`.  You copy the map and the list, but the elements they point to are the original elements.  You copy references to the elements only.  If that's OK, then OK.  But wanted to point that out.

Comment: There's a number of ways to do copy a map in Java using *deep* or *shallow* copy and *streams* [Java Copy HashMap](https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-hashmap).

Comment: Yeah, what I need is that changing the list of the initial map doesn't change the list of the copied map and vice-versa. I would like for the actual elements to reference the same instances. I will edit to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.BiFunction)) method of Map:

```
this.kvMap = new HashMap<>(map.kvMap);
this.kvMap.replaceAll((k, v) -> new ArrayList<>(v));
```

As markspace pointed out, this will clone the Lists, but if your keys and values are themselves mutable, they must individually be cloned for your Map to be a full clone.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

I guess this would be one of the fastest ways

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <K, V, T extends Collection<V>> Map<K, T> deepCopy(Map<K, ? extends Collection<V>> map) {
    Map<K, Collection<V>> cMap = new HashMap<>(map);
    for (Map.Entry<K, Collection<V>> entry : cMap.entrySet()) {
        Collection<V> list = entry.getValue();
        list = new ArrayList<>(list);
        entry.setValue(list);
    }
    return (Map<K, T>) cMap;
}
```

You can change ArrayList to LinkedList

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
this.kvMap = new HashMap<>(map.kvMap.size());
map.kvMap.forEach((k, v) -> this.kvMap.put(k, new ArrayList<>(v)));
```

It is very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64703601/1876620), but it creates entries once, when invoking `put`.

Comment: Does this have lower memory complexity compared to the other answer then?

Comment: @EthanThoma Memory complexity is the same, but in my answer, entries are added once. In the other answer, first the entries are created from the other map, and then each entry is replaced